# Does anyone know this Formula and a Proof/Context (Possibly-related to Cartan's Formula)

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm Trying to understand the formula; for $w$ a 2-form with d the exterior derivative

, and $X,Y$ vector fields; $[X,Y]$ is the Lie bracket:

$dw(X,Y)=X(w(Y))-Y(w(X))-w([X,Y])$

I was hoping someone may know about it; I think it follows from Cartan's Formula for the Lie derivative of a form .

Thanks for any explanation, refs. and, even better, a ref. for a proof.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof?  Or something more intuitive?

Comment: Both would be great, if possible; or with refs for both.

Comment: Are you sure $w$ isn't a *one-form*?

Comment: I have always taken this to be the *definition* of the exterior derivative $d\omega$ of a one form $\omega$. If you want a proof of the formula, then what is your definition of the exterior derivative?

Answer (score 2):

This indeed can be seen from Cartan's "Magic Formula"

$$\mathcal L_X dw = \iota_X dw + d(\iota_X w):$$

applying this to $Y$ and using the Leibniz rule for the LHS we have

$$X(dw(Y)) - dw( \mathcal L_X Y) = dw(X,Y) + Y(w(X))$$

as desired.

That being said, it should follow just as easily from whatever your definition of the exterior derivative is. For example if you define it in coordinates as the antisymmetrization of the partial derivative $dw_{ij} = \partial_i w_j - \partial_j w_i$, then
$$
\begin{align} 
dw(X,Y) = dw_{ij}X^i Y^j &= X(w_j)Y^j - Y(w_i)X^i \\
&= X(w_jY^j)-Y(w_iX^i)-(w_jX(Y^j) - w_iY(X^i)) \\
&=X(w(Y))-Y(w(X))-w([X,Y]).
\end{align}
$$